# Does abalone have any unique nutritional value that justifies its lofty prices?

Tags: seafood

I read that [wild abalone's illegal to sell and unsustainable, but abalone is still  expensive to farm](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-abalone-expensive) as they grow slowly and the algae and kelp for their diet are expensive.

1. I read https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/finfish-and-shellfish-products/4178/2 and https://www.eatthismuch.com/food/nutrition/abalone,3405/, but I don't know enough science to judge: are there nutrients unique to abalone that justifies its lofty prices? Or is abalone pricey only because of abalone's expensive production costs?
2. Is there any cheaper (combination of) foods that can yield the same nutrition?

Comment: Nutrition questions are off-topic.

Comment: You are making an assumption that the nutritional value is what defines the expense.  In some countries abalone (called ormer here in the UK) is protected, and harvesting them is limited to specific times/seasons, to avoid complete extinction of the species. This of course means the supply is lower than the demand, and so prices rise accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: People eat abalone because of [its taste, texture, and potential for gourmet preparation](https://www.foodrepublic.com/2014/05/19/mad-for-mollusks-what-exactly-is-abalone-and-why-do-we-love-it-so-much/).  Nutritional value isn't under consideration.